# css footer menu transition

Tags: css, transition

I have a problem trying to work out a small test menu with the (for me) "new" css3. The menu should be in the footer which always is on the bottom of the View port. However, I would like to mess around with the transition effects css3 offers therefore I want to grow a point of the menu when you `:hover` it.

The menu points are set to `float:left` in a relative menu div. The transition does as intended except the height transition enlarges the element downwards and (obviously as it is the footer) out of the page.
Instead I would like the menu points to grow upward. To solve this i could change the `float:left` to `position:absolute` and add `bottom:0`, but I would have to horizontal position every menu point (hyperlink) manually which I would like to avoid. Since the Menu size (number of menu points) should be variable and I also don't want to use and JavaScript, I am clueless.

Here is the css and the html:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="menu">
        <a href="#">menp1</a>
        <a href="#">menp2</a>
        <a href="#">menp3</a>
        <a href="#">menp4</a>
        <a href="#">menp5</a>
        <a href="#">menp6</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #497044;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 5px; }

div.menu {
  position: relative;
  height: 45px;
  width: 480px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -240px; }

div.menu a {
  float:left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px dashed;
  margin-left: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transition: height 2s; }
div.menu a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100px; }
```

thanks for the advice!

Comment: Create a jsfiddle, I think your problem is very difficult to understand without seeing it.  What I assume as the problem is that the menu appears below the footer. Am I correct.

Comment: Also you have allot of weird code. Change div.menu to this. div.menu {
  position: relative;
  height: 45px;
  width: 480px;
  margin: 0 auto; }

Comment: it seems like you are trying to center your footer, this is the best way to do so.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/MXJKZ/

Comment: ok i will take a look at jsfiddle. -- The code looks a bit weird yes i am generating it with sass. i can post this code here as it is more readable if desired. -- the problem with the menu is that when i hover over a menupoint the a element expands downward. i want it to expand upward

Comment: [jsfiddle.net/QGfsb/](http://jsfiddle.net/QGfsb/)

and here is the jsfiddle file. the side looks quite cool btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/nqCgu/2/

You mean something like this?

You can use a negative margin-top value and margin-top transition to achieve this. Add:

```
div.menu { ...
transition: margin-top .2s;
-moz-transition: margin-top .2s;}

div.menu a:hover {
margin-top:-50px;
background-color:white;
height: 100px; }
```

Comment: margin-top: -100px was what I was going to post. Nice job.

Comment: very nice! this totaly solved what i was trying to do. i was trying to add another `section` around the hyperlink but this is just elegant